# Problems running on iOS

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I've tried on 3 different computers but it still has the same problem that prevents me from running the project on the Mac. When I use Windows and connect to my Mac to run, it shows the same error on all 3 computers.

The error message displayed:

> Can not resolve reference: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarim.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lilb/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Memory.dll

Comment: Visual Studio version please

Comment: See [Troubleshooting Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/) and [Xamarin.iOS errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt2002-can-not-resolve-reference-)

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.7.3

Comment: VS Community Version 15.7.3

Comment: Versions of Visual Studio on Windows and Visual Studio and Xcode on MacOS should be [aligned](https://releases.xamarin.com/servicing-update-15-7-3/). Easiest to accomplish that is to update to the latest version.

Comment: I was getting the same error, By copying the whole project in MAC and run that project from MAC instead of connecting through VS helps me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Quick fix steps**

1. VS on PC:

   - in iOS poject open References list
   - find Xamarin.iOS and check the path in properties
   - open containing folder, open **Facades** folder, copy **System.Memory.dll**
2. Mac:

   - open Finder and *Go > Go to folder... >* type *Library*
   - find:

     > Library/Frameworks/Xamarim.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lilb/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/
   - paste **System.Memory.dll**

.. rebuild and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is usually do to a pending update for Xcode.

Make sure Xcode is installed and updated. Once it is updated, launch Xcode to ensure that all updates are finished(I don't know why, but a lot of times you have to run Xcode for the update to finalize.)

Then clean and rebuild your project. That should fix the issue.