# Error with Xamari iOs cannot resolve reference

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Can not resolve reference: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Memory.dll    Paga.iOS

Comment: You can find a quick fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417228/problems-running-on-ios/52385483#52385483